# Conservation of $\int |\psi|^2$ for Dirac wave

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

When $\psi$ be Schrodinger wave $\int |\psi|^2$ is conserved even when this wave interact whit another wave say electromagnetic wave. and this is very necessary for one particle interpretation of this wave.

When we deal with electromagnetic field with interaction by charges (in context of Maxwell theory) $\int E^2 + B^2$ is not conserved and I'm very OK whit it because this means electromagnetic field could get energy from charges and this is point of why this field after quantization (in context of QFT) is capable of creating new particles.

Now Dirac wave. Here there is some problems. Dirac equation somehow could be considered as one particle state and so again $\int |\psi|^2$ is conserved even during interactions with another fields. on the other hand in QFT this wave is considered some thing like electromagnetic wave and be quantized and I expect that during interaction whit electromagnetic wave we have some changes in $\int |\psi|^2$ just like as I said about electromagnetic wave. (for example when in empty space two colliding photons convert to electron and positron i expect Dirac field created and $\int |\psi|^2$ convert from zero two a positive number.)

Comment: None of the above quantities are waves in any sense. Moreover, what is the actual question?

Comment: Problem is the above integral conserved or not, in any case have some inconsistency with first two paragraphs @gented

Comment: But why are you assuming that they must be the same thing? One thing is the Schrödinger equation, another thing is the quantisation of the electromagnetic field, another thing is the Dirac equation. The quantities that those equations handle aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: Because one of the main ideas of QM (for example Debroglie idea's) and then QFT is to put all different particles in a somehow same perspective. @gented

Comment: QM and QFT are very formal theories that handle their own objects in order to make sense. You cannot just take fields and put them within the integral sign and claim that it should work likewise (also, the main ideas of QM and QFT aren't really what you exposed). It may be more useful I believe to formulate one precise question if you have a particular doubt so that people can reply precisely.